# facelet composition control (custom tag) with binding

Tags: jsf, facelets, icefaces, custom-tag

I'm having problems with creating a Facelet Composition Control (= custom tag).

That's the component's template (numberinput.jspx). I declared the  in my custom-taglib.xml.

So far the inclusion works using this code:

```
<ft:numberInput nullablenumber="true" cid="myId" 
                        bind="#{myBean.mySpecialComponent}"
                        value="#{myBean.license.myProperty }" 
                            label="My Label"/>
```

That's the template:

```
<div id="c_#{cid}"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:ft="http://www.mycomp.com/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" style="overflow:auto" >
    <ui:composition>    
    <ice:message for="#{cid}"></ice:message>
    <ice:outputLabel for="#{cid}">#{label }</ice:outputLabel>

    <ice:inputText          
        id="#{cid}"
        value="#{value}"        
        style="#{style }"   
        required="false"
        disabled="#{disabled }"
        binding="#{ bind}"
        >       
        <f:validator validatorId="notnull"/>    
        <f:converter converterId="nullableNumber"/>

    </ice:inputText> 
    </ui:composition>


</div>
```

My problems arise when I have multiple of these  tags on my page. I seems like Facelets gets confused and displays only a set of these, it's really very odd.

Is there anything wrong with my code or is Facelets just as buggy as it seems?

Thanks a lot.

From my current experience I only can discourage anyone to use Facelets custom tags (at least when component binding is used).

Environment info: I'm using ICEFaces 1.8.2 and Tomcat 6

Comment: Please elaborate "my problems".

Comment: Thanks, my (rather short) elaboration was eaten by an unclosed tag ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found! 
The reason for the problems were that 
I had a second ice:inputText control which was bound to the same backend bean proberty. it seems like this causes a lot of problems for JSF component tree generation.

My fault but it still would be nice if JSF gives any hints or error messages instead of just acting weird...